# Limiting external API calls in AWS architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, threadpool

in our microservices, we call our client's API (some external API) and for safety reasons, our client introduced a limit of concurrent calls to their API for us.

We have implemented a temporary solution using Hystrix and its bulkhead pattern implementation. In simple words, we configured a threadpool limiting these calls. It's a similar solution to BulkheadRegistry in Resilience4j.

With one service instance in AWS, it works just fine, but I'm sure it will stop working once we deployed more of the instance (since limiting external API calls is inside of the service - it's not shared between instances.

Do you have some ideas on how to limit these concurrent external API calls in AWS architecture?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do the API calls have to occur in realtime while the microservice is waiting for a response? Or would it be OK to queued them up and execute them later in a throttled manner?

Comment: I don't think it will stop working even with multiple instances. As long as you optimise the calls to the client's external API your calls are free to go. Just in cases where you reach the client's threshold of max concurrent calls, other call responses would get timed out but future calls will still work fine... For Eg. your client allows 40 max concurrent connections, and at a single point in time you send 42 requests, only those 2 last requests would be timed out. Other future requests would still work.

Comment: @MarkB I would like them to be somewhat close to real-time because there's a user expecting a response. What's your solution for not real-time?

Comment: @Patrick You're right. I was still hoping for not getting error responses from the external API.

Comment: @darianj. to limit these concurrent external API calls you can actually keep the invocation part under synchronized blocks or set the concurrent pool threshold of your app to the one equivalent to the client if you do not want any external call to timeout.

Comment: Another way is to use the messaging queues and setup limits there is queue listeners to pick max number of requests at a time.

Comment: @Patrick the question is asking how to handle this scenario once multiple servers are involved, which synchronized blocks and concurrent pools can't really manage without some sort of external coordinating service. And messaging queues, which I also was going to suggest, are going to be difficult in this scenario because they want to return a response to the user making the request.